# how to retrieve value from json data in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, jsonp, sencha-touch-2

my model is:

```
Ext.define('GS.model.user', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'username',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'email',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});
```

my store code is:

```
Ext.define('GS.store.userstore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'GS.model.user',
    config: {
        model: 'GS.model.user',
        autoLoad: true,
        // data: [],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/app/mydata.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'users'
            }
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function(store) {
            alert(store.getCount());
            console.log(store.getAt[0]);
        }
    }
});
```

view code:

```
Ext.define('GS.view.userlist', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'userpanel',
    requires: ['GS.store.userstore', 'Ext.form.Panel'],

    config: {
        itemTpl: '{store.get("id"),{sotre.get("username")},{store.get("email")}',
        store: 'userstore'
    }
});
```

Json data:

```
[{
    "users": [{
        "id": "1001",
        "username": "user1",
        "email": "abc@unisys.com"
    }, {
        "id": "1002",
        "username": "user2",
        "email": "abcd@unisys.com"
    }, {
        "id": "1003",
        "username": "user3",
        "email": "abce@unisys.com"
    }, {
        "id": "1004",
        "username": "user4",
        "email": "abcf@unisys.com"
    }]
}]
```

after running it at google chore i'm getting error:

```
OPTIONS file:///D:/app/mydata.json?_dc=1334569840508&page=1&start=0&limit=25
```

Resource failed to load.

please tell me how it's possible?
how can i retrieve json data value and populate it as a list.
help me.

Comment: OPTIONS file:///D:/app/mydata.json?_dc=1334569840508&page=1&start=0&limit=25. This shows that your request method is not GET. It seems weird.

Comment: No, that's not really weird. I suppose this is a regular [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) pre-flight request.

Comment: have you found a solution? where mydata.json must be put?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. Your JSON is valid, but it cannot be read by the JSON reader because it is an array. If you remove the `[` and `]` it will work:

   ```
   {
       "users": [
           {
               "id": "1001",
               "username": "user1",
               "email": "abc@unisys.com"
           },
          ...
       ]
   }
   ```
2. Inside your reader, you need to use `rootProperty` - not `root`:

   ```
   reader: {
       type: 'json',
       rootProperty: 'users'
   }
   ```
3. Within your `itemTpl` you can access fields directly using `{fieldName}` - you do not need to use `store.get('xxx')`:

   ```
   itemTpl: '{username}, {email}'
   ```

As for the file not loading; I'm not sure. Try a different browser and if it still doesn't work, check again that the file actually exists.

Comment: after doing all change as you said i tried but it shows same error.

Comment: if i put the mydata.json in to root folder and pass url as url:'mydata.json' it sjhows difffrent error.

Comment: error is:       XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/sencha/GS/mydata.json?_dc=1334634023782&page=1&start=0&limit=25. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: You need to put your Sencha Touch application onto a (local) webserver. It looks like you are trying to just run it using the filesystem. You can use something like WAMP to do that on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

use `localhost` in url to run you app

for example:

`http://localhost/your_app`

Answer (score 1):

Your json data doesn't seem right.

"users" shouldn't be between quotes and the same holds for all your "id" and "username" and "email" statements :

Json data:

```
{
   users:
      [
         { id: "1001", username: "user1" , email:"abc@unisys.com"},
         { id: "1002", username: "user2" , email:"abcd@unisys.com"},
         { id: "1003", username: "user3" , email:"abce@unisys.com"},
         { id: "1004", username: "user4" , email:"abcf@unisys.com"}
      ]
}
```

Comment: Incorrect. This is not valid JSON. Each property (including `users`) must have quotes. http://simonwillison.net/2006/Oct/11/json/

Answer (score 1):

Is the path wrong?  To me it can't even locate the file.

```
proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'app/mydata.json', // CHANGE THIS TO 'app/mydata.json'
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'users'
           }} },
```

I put your json into jsonlint.org and it passed, so I don't think that is the issue.  Based on the error, I don't think your path is correct.  If what I posted above didn't work, I'd copy the mydata.json into the root folder, where the index.html is located and just have the proxy url configured as url: 'mydata.json',

Comment: if i put mydata.json into root folder and pass url as a url:'mydata.json' then it gives error.

Comment: error is: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/sencha/GS/mydata.json?_dc=1334634023782&page=1&start=0&limit=25. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 0):

Host the json file in some location, that should be accessible over http.i.e place the file in any of the server running on your local machine ang give the URL in the url section of Proxy of store.